# Flutter location picker вылетает на реальном устройстве при выпуске apk

Tags: google-play, flutter, геолокация, location

Я использую [google_map_location_picker 4.1.6](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_location_picker), при тестировании на устройстве все работает. При загрузке приложения в GooglePlay, для внутреннего тестирования, приложение вылетает в тот момент, когда пытаюсь использовать google_map_location_picker.

Вот мой код:

**main.dart**

```
 void main() async {
      try {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
        Get.put(StateController());
        await GetStorage.init();
        await DB.init();
      } catch (err) {
        print('err $err');
      }
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          initialBinding: AuthBinding(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            location_picker.S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: const <Locale>[
            Locale('en', ''),
            Locale('ru', ''),
          ],
          theme: ...
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.name.com">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"  />
    
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Приложение"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="My_Key"/>
```

**Кнопка, по нажатию которой, вызываю Location Picker**

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
        final apiKeyIos = 'apiKeyIos';
        final apiKeyAndroid = 'apiKeyAndroid';
        try {
          showLocationPicker(
            context,
            Platform.isIOS ? apiKeyIos : apiKeyAndroid,
            initialCenter: LatLng(53.59575326915039, 142.9515826329589),
            initialZoom: 5,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            countries: ['RU'],
            language: 'ru',
            requiredGPS: true,
          );
        } catch (e) {
          Get.defaultDialog(
            title: 'Ошибка',
            middleText: e.toString(),
          );
        }
      }),
```

Comment: Смотрите логи, прикрутите crashlytics

Comment: Я, честно говоря, не знаю как это сделать с программой, которая запущена из PlayMarket.
Блоком Try Catch, я пытаюсь поймать ошибку и вывести ее на экран потом, но приложение просто закрывается.
Другого способа посмотреть, не знаю. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: crashlytics работает через firebase и ловит такие крашы. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/ Также можно попробовать через `adb logcat` https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю!

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, только при запуске установленного apk на реальном устройстве. Не подскажите, удалось ли вам узнать в чем проблема?

Comment: @ЕвгенийВолков не разобрался. Мне нужно было брать корректный адрес и координаты. Я воспользовался пакетом flutter_places.